# Most efficient way of using toString() JAVA

Tags: java, tostring

I have 2 classes of shapes one is rectangle and the second is circle, both extend "shape" class.

I should print the relevant info from each class for example x, y represent  a point which is relevant to all of the shapes and the color as well.
rectangle class has its width and height and circle has a radius.

I'm trying to use toString method in each class by overriding, using super and adding more info but one thing looks strange. should I create a new string builder object for each method? looks quite not right even though it works. Tried looking it up online but so far its either this or using a bunch of string. Am I missing something?

here is what I did in shape class:

```
public String toString() {
        StringBuilder shapeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(shapeBuilder.append("The x axis is: ").append(x).append(" and the y axis is: ").append(y).append(" The color of ")
        .append(this.getClass().getSimpleName()).append(" is ").append(color));
        return shapeBuilder.toString();
    }
```

rectangle class:

```
public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        StringBuilder rectangleBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(rectangleBuilder.append("The height of the rectangle is: ").append(height)
                .append(" And the width is: ").append(width));
        return rectangleBuilder.toString();
    }
```

circle class:

```
public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        StringBuilder circleBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(circleBuilder.append("the radius of the circle is: ").append(getRadius()));
        return circleBuilder.toString();
    }
```

I'm calling them from main using object name.toString();

Comment: Sorry, what is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: Make sure to use `@Override`. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Creating a new object for each method seems wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problems are

1. In your `Rectangle` and `Circle` class, you called `super.toString()` and do nothing with the result.  There is no reason calling it.  Or, I guess what you are trying to do is something like : (e.g. `Rectangle` )

   ```
   public String toString() {
       return super.toString() 
              + " height " + this.height 
              + " width " + this.width;
   }
   ```
2. In your case, you do not need to explicitly use `StringBuilder`.  Simply

   e.g. `Shape` class

   ```
   public String toString() {
        return "The x axis is: " + x 
             + " and the y axis is:" + y 
             + " The color of " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() 
             + " is " + color;
   }
   ```

   is good enough.  Always-use-StringBuilder is not necessary better.

Answer (score -1):

Use `System.out.println(super.toString()` to print/use super class toString().

Code Below:

```
 public class Shape {

    int x;
    int y;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shape [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }


}


public class Rectangle extends Shape{

    double width,height;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(super.toString());
        return "Rectangle [width=" + width + ", height=" + height + "]";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle rectangle=new Rectangle();
        rectangle.x=10;
        rectangle.y=30;
        rectangle.width=20;
        rectangle.height=100;

        System.out.println(rectangle);

    }

}
```